# AzurePerformanceDiagnostics extension Vs Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure and just want to know what is the difference in between Azure Performance Diagnostic Extension Vs Azure Log Analytics? or are they same functionality wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Performance Diagnostic Extension collects performance diagnostic data from VMs. The extension performs analysis, and provides a report of findings and recommendations to identify and resolve performance issues on the virtual machine.

Azure Log Analytics is a log aggregation tool, it will collect and store your data from various log sources and allow you to query over them using a custom query language. It collects not only performance data but also event log, as well as log aggregation.

If you just want to collect the performance data of VM, you could use Azure Performance Diagnostic Extension.  If you need to do anything more complex with this data or query across multiple resources, you could use Log Analytics.

Reference:

- [Performance diagnostics for Azure virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/performance-diagnostics)
- [Azure Performance Diagnostics VM Extension for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/performance-diagnostics-vm-extension)
- [View or analyze data collected with Log Analytics log search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-viewdata)
- [Azure Monitor and Azure Log Analytics](https://dzone.com/articles/azure-monitor-and-azure-log-analytics-when-to-use)

Comment: Can you give me examples of each where do I need to use Extensions or log analyrics? thanks